# How to override superclass' s NSNotificationCenter listener method?

Tags: objective-c, overriding, selector, observer-pattern, nsnotificationcenter

Say I have superclass which listens to a notification:

```
@implementation SuperClass

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo:) name:@"bar" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"bar" object:nil];
}

- (void)foo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //do something
}
```

Now in a subclass, I want to do something different with that notification. The first thing I tried is to override foo:

```
@implementation SubClass
- (void)foo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //do something different
}
```

This does not work since the listening selector still points to superclass's method. Then I tried to remove superclass's listener and add from subclass:

```
@implementation SubClass
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:(SuperClass *)self name:@"bar" object:nil];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(foo2:) name:@"bar" object:nil];
}

- (void)foo2:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  //do something different
}
```

This doesn't work either, with or without cast/override. The notification event is still handled by superclass. I'm not sure how NSNotificationCenter handles observers from same address but of different pointer type. And I don't want to touch superclass. Can anyone please help?

Comment: No-repro. When I set up a test program with the situation you describe, simply overriding the notification handler in the subclass causes that to be called, as I would expect.

Comment: Seeing your reply, I reexamined my code and found an irrelevant bug that caused the problem. After that both two methods above works fine, NSNotificationCenter has no problem figuring out which is which. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close this question by answering myself. The problem description should have stated clearly how NSNotificationCenter works with subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:[self superclass] name:@"bar" object:nil];

Comment: `[self superclass]` would be a `Class` object, not an instance, right?

Comment: Well, if you got a reference to an instance of your super class, then you could use that as the "observer" parameter to removeObserver method.